# Android Multi Language Support

Tags: android

In my android application, I've to provide two language versions (GERMAN,ENGLISH) of the application.In the German Version ,Some extra categories(extra screens) are available compared to English Version.What are the best practices,I should follow?

Answer (score 2):

You have to make two folder in the res directory.

*values (This is the by default, put English Language here.)*

*values-in(This is for Indonesia language), similarlyyou can find for other languages too.*

In both the folder, you will having one file named strings.xml.

Now put all your strings in this two files, with the same refrence name.

Like below.

in values-in/strings.xml

```
<string name="date">Tanggal</string>
```

in values/strings.xml

```
<string name="date">Date</string>
```

and use this method in your MainActivity Class.

```
 public void changeLanguage(String lang) {
        Locale myLocale;
        if (lang.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
            return;
        myLocale = new Locale(lang);
        Locale.setDefault(myLocale);
        android.content.res.Configuration config = new android.content.res.Configuration();
        config.locale = myLocale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    }
```

Comment: I create two values folder to support two language, and put this code in MainActivity, it works perfect. `private void setLocale(){
        Locale.setDefault(new Locale(Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()));
    }`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the user language using -

```
Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();
```

and then maybe using `if else` and a boolean data type you may program your system accordingly.

Or you may want the user to select his or her language themselves using `RadioButtons`.

Use @strings for the Text Content as then you can translate them easily using coding

Answer (score 0):

You need to create string.xml file for both GERMAN,ENGLISH language with same key with different language text.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create two folder's in your resource directory named as 'values' and 'values-de' for English and German Language respectively. Also, you can design layouts based on device language. for ex. layout folder for English and layout-de folder for the German Language. Same way to set the font sizes of TextViews you can create a file named as dimen.xml in values folder for respective languages.

Answer (score 0):

// I added this code in every activity and it worked and ofcoarse u need to add a translation string first

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_log_in) 

    changeLang = findViewById(R.id.changeLang)
    changeLang.setOnClickListener {
        baseContext.setAppLocale("am")
        recreate() }

}
```

private fun Context.setAppLocale(language: String): Context {

```
    val locale = Locale(language)
    Locale.setDefault(locale)
    val config = resources.configuration
    config.setLocale(locale)
    config.setLayoutDirection(locale)
    return createConfigurationContext(config)

}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I added this code in every activity and it worked and ofcoarse u need to add a translation string first